# Hosting the WordPress website on someone else's web URL

Tags: redirect

Its my first attempt at any sort of web development with WordPress or otherwise. I volunteered to create a website for an Organization with whom I am temporarily working for a project. I don't want to set up the website at my end and forward the files to them (we are in different cities), since  updating the web pages later on may be a hassle for me (I guess).

My question, how do I achieve the following with WordPress-

I keep the files at my end and host the website at a server at my end, at (say) `the-ip-address/wordpress`. But the URL of the website remains what that Organization wants it to be, say, `wwww.their-homepage/several/sub-directories/wordpress`.

What all will my colleagues at the other end need to do to allow this re-direction?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a wordpress problem, it's a DNS problem, so the best thing you can do is to ask your or their provider. Generally, I would ask their provider to point the DNS to your server.

In your end, to develop the site, I suggest to use a virtual host in your machine (for example using MAMP), so you can test with the final host. Otherwise you will need a find/replace on the DB when you activate the production site (and also adjust wp-config.php)

Hope it helps